# Spring webclient throwing block not supported exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, resttemplate, spring-webclient

I am trying to make an HTTP call from `spring-boot`. The call is working fine in post man, below is the `curl` version of the call,

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://sampletest.com:8811/rest/oauth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=126763****ghsei99****' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=126763****ghsei99****' \
--data-urlencode 'param1=pppp' \
--data-urlencode 'param2=pppp'
```

But the same call I am trying to make using `WebClient`.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("https://sampletest.com:8811")
                    .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE).build();

            MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            formData.add("client_id","126763****ghsei99****");
            formData.add("client_secret", "126763****ghsei99****");
            formData.add("param1","pppp");
            formData.add("param2","pppp");

            AuthenticationResponseBean authenticationResponseBean = webClient.post().uri("/rest/oauth/token").body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
                    .retrieve().bodyToFlux(AuthenticationResponseBean.class).blockLast();
```

But, the app is throwing the exception,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are
>   blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3

What is going wrong here? I am very new to `reactive-programming` and the google search for the problem indicates why is the `block` needed?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, blocking actually blocks the thread. From the [ProyectReactor docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#blockLast--):

- "block indefinitely until the upstream signals its last value or
  completes".

So you dont need it if you dont need blocking, or you dont need to wait for the last element. So just subscribing could work, depending on your needs.